# How to add up values in the table row which is retrieved from MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sum

What I want to is add values in a table row retrieved from MySQL.

This is my PHP file:

```
<?php

mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
mysql_select_db('accounts');
$sql= "SELECT * FROM users1";
$list=mysql_query($sql);

?>
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome to ScanNShop</title>
</head>
<h1>Welcome to ScanNShop</h1>

<body>

<table width="600" border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1">
<tr>

<th>No.</th>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Price</th>
<tr>

<?php

while ($users1=mysql_fetch_assoc($list)) {

echo "<tr>";

echo "<td>".$users1['pid']."</td>";

echo "<td>".$users1['name']."</td>";

echo "<td>".$users1['price']."</td>";

}

?>

</table>
</body>
</html  >
```

This is the output from the PHP file.

```
No. Name    Price
1   bread   2.00
2   milk    2.00 
3   janabab 6797994.00
4   jajajsh 846494.00
```

I want to add up all the price and display an `echo "Total:" thetotal`

Comment: Have you made an attempt to do this at all?  You are looping through the result set, do you think it might be a good idea to sum  up the values as you iterate in the loop?

Comment: hey! im really new to php and i appreciate all the help! thank you though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I kept your code easy and add the change's 
I could give you an other code but this is easy to understand if your learning php

I added a comment by the change's

```
mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
mysql_select_db('accounts');
$sql= ('SELECT * FROM users1');
$list=mysql_query($sql);

?>
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome to ScanNShop</title>
</head>
<h1>Welcome to ScanNShop</h1>

<body>

<table width="600" border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1">
<tr>
<th>No.</th>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Price</th>
</tr>

<?php
 //set total to zero
$total=0;
while ($users1=mysql_fetch_assoc($list)) {

echo "<tr>";

echo "<td>".$users1['pid']."</td>";

echo "<td>".$users1['name']."</td>";

echo "<td>".$users1['price']."</td>";
//set total to the price + the previous total
$total = $users1['price']+$total;

echo "</tr>";

}
//display total
echo '<tr><td></td>';
echo '<td>Total:</td>';
echo '<td>'.$total.'</td></tr>';

?>

</table>
</body>
</html  >
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to sum data rows across is within the SQL query itself by using [GROUP BY .. WITH ROLLUP (doc)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-modifiers.html).

Example:

```
SELECT Number, Min(Name) AS Name, SUM(amount) AS Price
  FROM grocery_list
 GROUP BY Number WITH ROLLUP
```

Will produce the output:

```
Number  Name      Price
1       bread     2.00
2       milk      2.00 
3       janabab   6797994.00
4       jajajsh   846494.00
NULL    bread     7644492.00
```

The Line with NULL is the MIN(name), SUM(Price) across *ALL* records for the group 'Number'.
You can then filter your output based on which field is NULL to determine how to display.

Answer (score 0):

May be you need just to sum results in special variable?

```
$sum = 0;
while ($users1=mysql_fetch_assoc($list)) {
    $sum += $users1['price'];

    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>'.$users1['pid'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$users1['name'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$users1['price'].'</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}

echo '<tr>';
echo '<td></td>';
echo '<td>Total</td>';
echo '<td>'.$sum.'</td>';
echo '<tr>';
```

Do not use double quotes (") for strings. Use single quotes (');
And do not use mysql_* functions, they are deprecated.

Comment: While I generally prefer to use single quotes around most strings, there is no hard and fast rule to NOT use double quotes around strings, nor should there be. A good developer will know when best to use each. For example when writing out SQL queries which have single quoted strings in them, I find it make the code easier to read to use double quotes around the SQL statement string so as to not have to escape the single quotes in the command itself. To me give out such flawed advice to a new user. They need to understand both uses.